# Does solr make faceting on empty String?

Tags: xml, indexing, lucene, solr

Last time I made a solr index, it started indexing and doing faceting on empty strings too. This never happened. It is the right behaviour? Should I filter empty strings in the DIH?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend filtering them out (setting them to NULL) in your Data Import Handler to reduce the load time it takes to generate the potentially large facet count. This may present itself regularly when optional values are represented as empty strings in a dataset.